# git gh-pages deployment permissions error “Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository”

Tags: ssh, git, github, ssh-keys

**EDIT: POSSIBLE FIX**

In addition to the answers submitted, anyone with this error/same issue could also try running the command `$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. This seems to work for me any time I need to get passed this error!

---

I'm very very new to using git and I've never deployed to gh-pages before, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I put in the homepage, dependencies, and scripts in my `package.json` file and when I run `$ yarn run deploy` everything works until the very end. It tells me it's ready to be deployed to the page I want, and then it gives me this error:

```
Cloning into 'node_modules/gh-pages/.cache/git@github.com!emilybossiere!GrabBag.git'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I've followed the GitHub instructions for [this specific error](https://help.github.com/en/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey), which led me to [this page](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) about checking for an SSH key. I've been successfully pushing to this repo the entire time I've worked on the application, so I know it's authenticated and it works, but for some reason deployment doesn't work.

This is my output when I run `$ ssh -vT git@github.com`

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/emilybo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/emilybo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/emilybo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/emilybo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/emilybo/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/emilybo/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/emilybo/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/emilybo/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-80573d3e
debug1: no match: babeld-80573d3e
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/emilybo/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/emilybo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.255.112]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Hi emilybossiere! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2724, received 2236 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 31128.3, received 25551.7
debug1: Exit status 1
```

So it seems to connect just fine, so when I do `$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` it returns `> Agent pid 59566` as it should, but when I run `$ ssh-add -l -E md5`, it tells me `The agent has no identities.` Does this mean it's not actually authenticated?

Also, step 2 of [this page](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) says something about automatically loading keys into the ssh agent, but I've never done this before and I'm not sure how to modify my `~/.ssh/config` file but I don't even seem to have one? How do I modify this file if it doesn't exist? :(

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting this error and you use a passphrase for git authentication then this solution may work for you:

1. cd ~ and open a file called .bashrc and add these lines

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
```

This assumes that your key is in the conventional ~/.ssh/id_rsa location. If it isn't, 
  include a full path after the ssh-add command.

Add to or create file ~/.ssh/config with the contents

```
ForwardAgent yes
```

2. restart your terminal (You might want to reboot your system first)
3. You should be prompted for your passphrase
4. Now try `npm run deploy`

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users here is the fix:

1. Edit `C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.ssh\config`
2. Add to the config file:

```
Host github.io
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.ssh\your_key.pub
```

3. Run the deploy from Git Bash instead of your IDE's terminal or you won't get the password prompt.

Comment: you made a typo in the config file path (missing a slash before `.ssh`)